# addition of two 8 bit numbers in 8086 giving wrong answer

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16, emu8086

I made this 8086 masm program to add two 8 bit numbers 54h and 13h which is supposed to give 67h as the answer but is giving 07 as answer. can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code?

This is my code

```
; addition of two 8bit numbers

data segment
num1 db 54h
num2 db 13h
data ends

code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data 

start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax


mov al,num1
mov bl,num2
add al,bl

mov ah,00h
aaa

mov dl,ah
mov dh,al

add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h

mov dl,dh
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Comment: Have you consulted the instruction set reference? Did you notice it says _"The AAA instruction is only useful when it follows an ADD
instruction that adds (binary addition) two unpacked BCD values"_? Clearly this does not apply to your case. You could try `DAA` but that has packed BCD for both input and output so you need more changes. Also it's not entirely clear if you even want BCD arithmetic.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to abuse AAA as part of printing 2 hex digits of your result byte.  That's the only problem.  Use a debugger to look at AL after `add`.

Answer (score 3):

67h is 103d. The decimal number has three digits. You cannot convert this hexadecimal number into an unpacked bcd number (two bytes) under any circumstances. But maybe you wanted to treat 67h as a packed BCD number. There is no x86 instruction to convert a packed bcd number to an unpacked bcd number, you have to isolate the nibbles by yourself.

Change

```
mov ah,00h
aaa

mov dl,ah
mov dh,al
```

to

```
mov dl,al
mov dh,al
shr dl, 4
and dh, 0Fh
```

Comment: Technically `aam 16` would do `ah = al/16` and `al = al % 16`, but that's *very* slow using the divider hardware.  The AAM mnemonic defaults to an immediate divisor of `10`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aam.  If you only care about code-size, and performance doesn't matter at all, then that's a fun nibble-unpack trick, with quotient / remainder reversed vs. `div r8` and an immediate divisor.  (And dividend = AL not AX).